# Adding path on openssl

Tags: android, ssl, android-ndk

I am new to developing an android app. my question is how can i add openssl header file and path in android.mk file.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := HelloJni

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := /Users/accelpro/Downloads/Compressed/openssl

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := HelloJni.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

and build with ndk in android studio.  above i added path to openssl but it does not build it shows many error.

error is:

```
fatal error: openssl/ssl.h: No such file or directory
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
```

anyone have solution. plzz rly me. thanks in advance

Comment: Well, does `/Users/accelpro/Downloads/Compressed/openssl/openssl/ssl.h` exist?

Comment: yes ssl.h exist in openssl folder

Comment: But does it exist in `/Users/accelpro/Downloads/Compressed/openssl/openssl/`, or in `/Users/accelpro/Downloads/Compressed/openssl/` ?

Comment: it exist in /Users/accelpro/Downloads/Compressed/openssl/

Comment: In that case what you should add to `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES` is `/Users/accelpro/Downloads/Compressed/`.

Comment: Now I change its path to jni folder where my c code are there. I create a openssl folder and paste all header file. openssl folder are in jni folder.

Comment: Now finally my path is /Users/accelpro/Downloads/Compressed/AccelPro/app/src/main/jni